# Updating chunks of a column faster than loc inside itertuples

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following code which iterates over a dataframe and updates chunks of a column depending on two other columns. The current solution uses `loc` inside `itertuples`.

Is it possible to make the code faster without resorting to manual parallelization or splitting the dataframe up?

```
n_rows = 10000
ix_ = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01 00:00", freq="min", periods=n_rows)
offsets_ = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 60, size=n_rows), unit="min")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    ix_ + pd.to_timedelta(offsets_, unit="min"), index=ix_, columns=["t_end"]
)
df["active"] = 0
for row in df.itertuples():
    df.loc[row.Index : row.t_end, "active"] += 1
```

Comment: If you want to count up the 'active' column, this can be done.`df["active"] = np.arange(1, n_rows+1)`

Comment: Sorry @r-beginners, this is not what I am trying to do here. The `active` value does depend on two other `df` columns as stated in the problem.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, there might still be a way to avoid looping altogether. Would you mind providing additional details on how `"active"` is calculated?

Comment: @gofvonx this is all there is to it -- the whole calculation of `"active"` is given in the question. I would be thrilled to avoid looping :)

Comment: @jarm Yes - apologies. I haven't read your code properly. Check out my solution below avoiding the loop. It's unfortunately not really any more efficient than other answers posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that runs in ~2 milliseconds (so, ~3000 times faster than the original version and ~1000 times faster than other solutions proposed here).

We can make an observation that we're essentially adding up intervals defined by their start and end timestamps, so we can use the following to calculate activity in a vectorized form:

1. Set `+1` at the location of each interval's start and `-1`
   right after the location of its end
2. Sum these markers
   and get at each point in time the net value of how many intervals
   started/ended
3. Taking cumulative sum of this will give us the number
   of 'active' intervals at each point in time

Here's what happens visually:

[image: picture]

In code it would look like this:

```
def f_proposed(df):
    z = df.copy()
    z['active'] = (z['active']
                       .add(1)                  # add start markers
                       .sub(df                  # subtract end markers
                            .groupby('t_end')   # at each 't_end'
                            .size()             # count end markers
                            .reindex(df.index)  # reindex to original
                            .shift()            # shift end markers by 1 row
                            .fillna(0)          # fill missing values with 0s
                            .astype(int))       # convert back to int
                       .cumsum())               # take cumulative sum
    return z
```

And the timings (execution time went from ~6 seconds to ~2 milliseconds) + a test that we get correct output:

```
%%timeit
f_original(df)
# 6.66 s ± 25.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
f_proposed(df)
# 2.06 ms ± 7.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# test
z_original = f_original(df)
z_proposed = f_proposed(df)
z_proposed.equals(z_original)
# True
```

P.S. For `f_original` I'm using:

```
def f_original(df):
    z = df.copy()
    for row in df.itertuples():
        z.loc[row.Index : row.t_end, "active"] += 1
    return z
```

**Update:** here's the code for the illustration:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.zeros((3, 10))
x[(2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 2)] = 1
x[(2, 1, 0), (4, 7, 6)] = -1
v = 3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 6))

# markers
ax[0].set_title('Markers:\nblue "start" (+1)\nred "end" (-1)')
ax[0].pcolormesh(x,cmap='RdBu', vmin=-v, vmax=v, edgecolors='w')

# net started/ended
ax[1].set_title('Net started/ended =\nSum of markers')
ax[1].pcolormesh(
    np.sum(x, axis=0)[None, :],
    cmap='RdBu', vmin=-v, vmax=v, edgecolors='w')

# activity
ax[2].set_title('Activity =\nCumulative sum')
im = ax[2].pcolormesh(
    np.cumsum(np.sum(x, axis=0))[None, :],
    cmap='RdBu', vmin=-v, vmax=v, edgecolors='w')

for x in ax:
    x.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    x.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    x.set_aspect('equal')
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution way beyond what I expected -- many thanks @perl , bounty assigned. Would you mind also sharing the visualization snippet? It looks very neat.

Comment: @jarm Yes, sure! Shared the code for the illustration in the Update section

Comment: This is genius! A small caveat: As far as I can tell this will only work if `t_end` has the same frequency as the index. Otherwise, `reindex` would introduce `NaN`s, correct?

Comment: @gofvonx Thanks! You're totally right, but for those cases there's an easy fix -- you just need to pre-process `t_end`s making them equal to the last index where `index <= t_end` (this can be done in linear time, so won't materially affect the performance)

Answer (score 2):

It's 3-4 times faster if you do the computation on a NumPy array rather than on the pandas Series:

```py
df['int_index'] = range(len(df))
active = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=int)

for row in df.itertuples():
    active[df.int_index.loc[row.Index : row.t_end]] += 1
        
df['active'] = active
```

Comment: Indeed, the original function takes 7.5 s, whereas your version does the job in 2.0 s. Thank you for your input @Arne .

Comment: Very nice! Any insight on what exactly causes this to be so much faster?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution avoiding explicit looping over the index. Performance-wise it seems to be comparable with [Arne's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122668/updating-chunks-of-a-column-faster-than-loc-inside-itertuples/67163885#67163885).

```
idx_prod = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ix_, ix_ + pd.to_timedelta(offsets_, unit="min")], names=['t_start', 't_end'])
condition = idx_prod.get_level_values('t_start')<=idx_prod.get_level_values('t_end')
condition.reshape(n_rows, n_rows).sum(axis=-1) - np.arange(n_rows)[::-1]
```

The basic observation is that the loop above counts the number of occurrences that an element `t1` in the index falls between a previous `t0` and its corresponding `t_end`. This is equivalent to the number of elements in `t_end` larger than `t1` (corresponding to `condition.reshape(n_rows, n_rows).sum(axis=-1)`) minus the number of elements in the index smaller than `t1` (corresponding to `np.arange(n_rows)[::-1]`).

Comment: Thanks @gofvonx -- no loop as promised and I got to learn about MultiIndices from your solution, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

without `df.itertuples()` and use of `np.apply_along_axis`, there is a marginal improvement in performance

```
df['ix_'] = ix_
df['intx'] = np.arange(n_rows) 
active = np.zeros(n_rows, dtype=int)

def update_active(row):
   active[df.intx.loc[row[0] : row[1]].values]+=1

np.apply_along_axis(update_active, 1, df[['ix_','t_end']].values)
df['active'] = active
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly faster method than iterating over it in numpy.  Build an array to represent all of the timedeltas.  The maximum time delta is 60 minutes, so the array is nrows by 60.  If the timedelta is 10, then that row is 10 ones followed by 50 zeros.  Then you sum across the diagonal of the array using np.trace.  If your timedelta was 10 minutes, and you are in the 10 rows following that, then the diagonal will contain a 1 for the row.  If not, then it's a 0.  That way your diagonal sum will contain all the timedeltas that are currently active.

```
n_rows = 10000
ix_ = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01 00:00", freq="min", periods=n_rows)
offsets_ = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 60, size=n_rows), unit="min")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    ix_ + pd.to_timedelta(offsets_, unit="min"), index=ix_, columns=["t_end"]
)
df["active"] = 0

offsets = (offsets_.seconds / 60).astype(int) + 1

duration_array = np.zeros((10000, 60), dtype=int)
for i, value in enumerate(offsets):
    duration_array[i, :value] = 1.0

for i, x in enumerate(range((duration_array.shape[1] - 1), -duration_array.shape[0] + (duration_array.shape[1] - 1), -1)):
    df.iloc[i, 1] = np.trace(np.fliplr(duration_array), x)
```

This is the times I recorded among the existing methods.

```
base_method took 7.874sec
np_method took 2.133sec
sum_diag_method took 2.019sec
```